# Excel search and add rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have searched this site and I am a newb but trying to modify code a friend made.  Currently it searches for a row (rowname) and when matches (prodcat) takes the data from one spreadsheet and records it into another (dashboardFile).  The problem is, I have multiple rows with the same (prodcat) so instead of recording right away, I want to keep searching and if it finds another of the same (prodcat), adds the data and records.  Hopefully this makes sense to someone.  Here is the code

```
    Windows(FYfile).Activate
    Sheets("Product by Branch").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Do Until datayear = 7 '5
        datayear = datayear + 1

        foundsap = False
        sapRow = 5

        Do Until foundsap = True
            div = ActiveCell.Offset(sapRow - 1, 0).Range("A1").Value
            If InStr(div, sap) > 0 Then
                prodrow = sapRow + 1
                foundsap = True
                endDiv = False
                foundMatch = False
                Do Until endDiv = True Or foundMatch = True
                    rowname = ActiveCell.Offset(prodrow - 1, 0).Range("B1").Value
                    'MsgBox (rowname)
                    If prodcat = rowname Then
                        'MsgBox (rowname & " matches " & prodcat & " on row " & prodrow)
                        foundMatch = True
                        If datayear > 5 Then
                            datum = ActiveCell.Offset(prodrow - 1, 0).Cells(1, 4 + datayear).Value
                        Else
                            datum = ActiveCell.Offset(prodrow - 1, 0).Cells(1, 3 + datayear).Value
                        End If
                        'MsgBox (datum)
                    ElseIf InStr(rowname, "Prod Cat") > 0 Then
                        endDiv = True
                        'MsgBox ("Didn't find " & prodcat)
                        datum = 0
                    End If

                    prodrow = prodrow + 1
                Loop

                'switch to Charts and record datum
                Windows(dashboardFile).Activate
                Sheets("Charts").Select
                Range("A1").Select
                ActiveCell.Offset(43 * (boxes - 1) + 1, 0).Range("A1").Select
                ActiveCell.Offset(sectionrows + metric, sectionCols + datayear + 1).Range("A1").Value = datum
                'switch back to FY
                Windows(FYfile).Activate
```

Comment: The most efficient way would be to reverse the order of your search and start from the end of data instead of the first row

Comment: You are essentially asking us to refactor (re-write) your code for you, which is outside the scope of this site. see [mcve] for more

Comment: ok, thanks.  This is my first post and not sure what is accepted or not.